# Sencha ExtJS - understanding views

Tags: extjs, view

I am new in Sencha Ext (5.0) and I would like to add main template (view) to my app and inject into this main view some other view (For example i would like to add datagrid view into main view).

Could somebody post link where is it described nice and simple ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to keep it short: This link shows [whats new in ExtJs5](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/whats_new/5.0/whats_new.html)
>
> A simple fiddle using ExtJs5 : [ExtJs5 Demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6h5)

You can always refer [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/getting_started) for more details for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sencha generate app`. The result is a sample application that contains main view, some other views, view model, view controller, some listeners etc. From there you can proceed to what you need, of course using advices from @Dev answer.